# structured reference in excel vba: using '#Headers [col-name]' in Range

Tags: excel, vba

folks, 
not quite sure how to present this properly. so bear with with me:

1. i have an excel vba userform, and would like to do a calc inside the userform, retrieving data from a cell in an xls worksheet
2. the cell i can select is in col 'A' (GrossSales) and any row in the Revenue table; the selected cell then identifies 'active cell.row'. NOW, the column i want for specific data is defined elsewhere in a different column - the column could be found by #Headers[Sales]
3. since the worksheet is in development, i keep moving columns around; so i would like to use a 'dynamic' reference to the name of the column, rather than a 'static' name using column letter [like col 'H']

so, how it works, i click on a cell in col 'A' in a worksheet, and the userform gets me the active row: ActiveCell.Row; and currently, the xls has been 'static', so the column is simply identified as "H". in the userform then, i get my specific value to calc using Me.Sales.Value = Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value

what i need to is to replace "H" with a header row 'name' so if i move columns this link still works. 
i tried this:
Me.txtSales.Value = Range("Table_Revenue[[#Headers],[Sales]]" & ActiveCell.Row).Value 
and i get this error:
..run time error 1004.. ..Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

so the reference to [#Headers],[Sales] is not returning the equivalent of the old "H"

can anyone tell me what i am missing here?
probably my lack of understanding of what is 'inside' the reference Table_Revenue[[#Headers],[Sales]]. it clearly isn't equal to H.
i tried putting the reference into a MsgBox to display, but that failed as well.

thanks,
ron

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use the `ListObject` instead:

```
Me.txtSales.Value = Intersect(Activecell.Entirerow, Activesheet.Listobjects("Table_Revenue").Listcolumns("Sales").Range).Value
```

Comment: rory, thanks for the hint. i can't get it to work as yet, but i learned about the 'intersect' function. excellent. makes sense. tried this on a 3*3 using intersect(activecell.entirerow, activecell.entirecolumn). works. easy i guess.  however, once i put in the list objects stuff, i get syntax error. i also tried to do  a msgbox around listobjects portion to see what it would return = i get a run time error '9' ok, well, still working on this. and very much appreciate your help with intersect.      ron

Comment: rory - ok, found the error. i labelled the column header Net Sales [with a space in-between Net and Sales. it seems the column header doesn't like spaces in the column name. took out the space and works fine. thank you very much.

Comment: @rny1so A space in the name should not be a problem - what was the error message?

Answer (score 0):

rory,
u are correct. i was experimenting to understand range & value [i am still very wet behind the ears w/excel & vba]. i tried these things:

1. Me.txtSales.Value = Intersect(Activecell.Entirerow, Activesheet.Listobjects("Table_Revenue").Listcolumns("Sales").Range)
   with dim txtSales Variant and then with dim txtSales Range
2. Me.txtSales = Intersect(Activecell.Entirerow, Activesheet.Listobjects("Table_Revenue").Listcolumns("Sales").Range).Value
   with dim txtSales Variant

and #2 worked right, with the space between "Net Sales". so, as you said - it should work and it did.
what i think i found as well was that this version:
Range("Table_Revenue[[#Headers],[Sales]]" & ActiveCell.Row).Value 
was commented as only working in excel, and not in vba.

one last thing: ListObjects worked because it was a 'table'? if it wasn't a table, but defined as a 'range', would it have worked?

anyway, i learned a lot - so thankyou very much for the solution, but thanks more for the learning experience.

ron